# Azure App Service Deployments - Minimum Role for Service Principal Account

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, service-principal

I am deploying a standard ASP.NET MVC application to an Azure App Service using a VSTS build and release definition.  The VSTS instance and the target Azure subscription are on separate Azure accounts/subscriptions so we have create a Azure AD application and Service Principal account to authorize the deployment.

When adding the Service Principal account to the subscription, it wants us to assign a role.

What is the best and least privileged role that can be used to deploy the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When add Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint, it mentions:

> A new Azure Service Principal will be created and assigned with
>   "Contributor" role, having access to all the resources in the selected
>   subscription.

So, the Contributor role is better.

On the other hand, to configure Azure RM service endpoint, you must be a member of the **Global Admin role** in the directory. More information: [Insufficient privileges to complete the operation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/azure-rm-endpoint#insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation).